# Can we change our field of study for masters in canada?

Tags: masters, computer-science, canada

I have a bachelors degree in electronics and communication engineering and am going for higher studies. I want to change my field to computer science for my masters. Is it possible to do that for masters in Canada? I've been working as a software developer for an year now.

Comment: Maybe contact some computer science masters courses in Canada and find out? Every uni is different and the subjects in your engineering course would be different too. We don't tend to give career advice in Academic SE as it is opinion based and the variability of the answers is too broad and too much. Most answers can be found on university or course websites too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes definitely. Your master's field doesn't need to be in the same field as your bachelors degree in Canada. Although some programs may have specific requirements. Looking at the University of Toronto's website for graduate school in computer science (https://www.sgs.utoronto.ca/programs/computer-science/) the requirements are:

"An appropriate bachelor's degree with a standing equivalent to at least a University of Toronto B+. Preference given to applicants who have studied computer science or a closely related discipline."

Comment: Thanks for that. I wasn't sure how similar to the US is the undergrad  program in Canada. In the US this would be very possible for almost every field.